# rails session_store odd behaviour

Tags: session, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using active_record_store in a rails application which is storing this in session `session[:email] = "email@address.com"`

now this works fine in the action. but when this action gets over and is redirected to another page, which also accesses the same session[:email] I get an error

```
undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass
```

this should probably mean that i am trying to compare values at some place i am not allowed to. but i cannot see anything like that in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an old question, but I was just having the same problem and had to figure it out on my own, and thought I would post the solution up here for anyone else that runs into this. It's not very well documented, but to get this to work you have to add:

```
config.action_dispatch.session_store = :active_record_store
```

to application.rb, and

```
Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

to config/initializers/session_store.rb. Then, you have to do:

```
rake db:sessions:create
```

and:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Then, you have to restart your rails server. I think it was the db:sessions:create step that tripped up the original poster. Not only does that database table have to be laid out the way rails is expecting (that is, with an 'id' column, which is the actual cause of this error, I think), but also the current session has to have a valid ID. Hence the need to create the table and re-start the server, or potentially empty the table if it exists.